# JavaScript If / Else style changing

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, onclick

I have a problem with simple if/else statement that changes text color of a `<p>` element depending on the current color. I see why I get certain results but I can't seem to find a solution.

```js
var test = 1;

function one() {  
    x.style.fontSize = "18px";
    x.style.color    = "black";
}

function two() {
    x.style.fontSize = "18px";
    x.style.color    = "red";
}

function three() { 
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    if (test % 2 == 0) {
        one();
    } else {
        two();
    }
    test = test + 1;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="three()">Click Me!</button>
```

Any help for a newbie like me would be appreciated.

Comment: Function `three` is missing a terminating `}`. `vfunction` is not a valid Javascript keyword. Open your developer console (F12 in most browsers, Ctrl+Shift+I in Opera) and fix the errors.

Comment: I made a mistake copying code but fixing those two results in same way, thanks tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the element's color.

> window.getComputedStyle(x, null).color

Since the value of the [color](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp) property of your 'demo' element hasn't been initialized, it contains the default value of rgb(0, 0, 0) which corresponds to the color black.

See below for an example of toggling between two colors:

```js
var black = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
var red = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';

function toggleColor() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var currentColor = window.getComputedStyle(x, null).color;

  if(currentColor === black) {
    x.style.color = red;
  } else {
    x.style.color = black;
  } 
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">
  JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.
</p>
<input type="button" onclick="toggleColor()" value="Toggle Color">
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use a variable to cache current color, for example:

```
(function(){
  var color = 'red';

  var demoEl = document.getElementById("demo");
  demoEl.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (color === 'red') {
          demoEl.style.color = 'black';
          color = 'black';    // set current color
      } else {
          demoEl.style.color = 'red';
          color = 'red';
      }
  }, false);
})();

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), `style` is used for inline CSS.